# How to use recyclesignalenabled in nodejs from Azure Api

Tags: node.js, azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide#recyclesignalenabled

```
const gracefulShutdown = async () => {
  console.log('Gracefully shutdown');
...
};
```

How do I call this function through Azure ?

```
process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
  console.log('Process exited (via SIGTERM)');

  await gracefulShutdown();
});

process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
  console.log('Process exited (via SIGINT)');

  await gracefulShutdown();
});
```

Should it be used this way or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

**`recycleSignalEnabled` is used to configure iis, so it can only be set in web.config.**

*It should be like below.*

[1. Not picking up node.exe despite being in path #302](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/302)

[image]

[2. watchedFiles relative directory problem #257](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/257)

[image]

Comment: It's clear. How can I intercept the signal and call my function?

Comment: @AxllLow https://imgur.com/2dLTq86  Make your app `Always on`.